# AVSpeechSynthesizer only working once

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, text-to-speech, avspeechsynthesizer

I have a swift app using a `UICollectionView`. Each cell in the `UICollectionView` has a view controller displaying some text. I've added two buttons to start and pause an `AVSpeechSynthesizer` reading the text. The two functions are:

```
    func playclicked(){
    if isInitial {
        let textString = (postTitle.text ?? "") + ".\n\n" + postContentWeb.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "document.body.textContent")!
        synth = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
        myVoice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: "de-DE")
        myUtterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: textString)
        myUtterance.voice = myVoice
        synth.speak(myUtterance)
        synth.delegate = self
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = isPlayingButtons
        isInitial = false
    } else {
        synth.continueSpeaking()
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = isPlayingButtons
    }
}

func pauseclicked(){
    synth.pauseSpeaking(at: .word)
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = isStoppedButtons
}
```

For one view starting and stopping of the reading works, but if I select another cell the speech output stops working at all, even if I reselect the cell where it had been working before. Only a restart of the app solves the problem.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53626384/9224215) could help.

Answer (score 1):

I've run into this issue before while playing around with the AVSpeechSynthesizer API.

When playing and pausing the syntesizer, you are correctly using the methods:

continueSpeaking() and pauseSpeaking(at: .word)

When you want to dismiss the ViewController before the synthesizer is finished speaking, utilize this method instead:

synthesizer.stopSpeaking(at: .immediate)